# How to find substring of whole column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am trying to find substring between two characters on a column
For eg

The column has

```
Bought ____ by manager
Bought ____ by employee
Bought ____ by other
```

The blank is always in between Bought and by.
I am trying to seperate the values in the blank? Can any one help me

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?  You have both tagged, which one is it?

Answer (score 0):

Your question has both tags `MySQL/SQL Server` so if you have `SQL Server` you can use `SUBSTRING` and `PATINDEX`:

```
CREATE TABLE #tab(col VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO #tab
SELECT 'Bought AAAAAAAAA by manager'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Bought BB by employee'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Bought C by other';

SELECT col,
 SUBSTRING(col, 8, PATINDEX('% by%', col)-8)
FROM #tab;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/409516)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════════════════════════════╦═══════════╗
║             col             ║  result   ║
╠═════════════════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ Bought AAAAAAAAA by manager ║ AAAAAAAAA ║
║ Bought BB by employee       ║ BB        ║
║ Bought C by other           ║ C         ║
╚═════════════════════════════╩═══════════╝
```

The start point is fixed 8, the length is calculated as position of space before `by` minus fixed 8.

---

`MySQL` version using `LOCATE`:

```
SELECT col,
 SUBSTRING(col, 8, LOCATE(' by', col)-8) AS result
FROM tab;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c871b9/1/0)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length )

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use below mentioned code : -

```
select left(col1,charindex(' ',col1)-1) as val1, ltrim(substring(col1,charindex(' ',col1),len(col1))) as val2
from mytable
```